# Android jni NoSuchMethodError exception

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, native, jnienv

I am trying to call java method from C++ lib. The methods of java are in my android application.

but while getting the method call , i am getting the exception ;

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/pkg/tpap/MainActivity;.getDataFromLibLjava/lang/String"
>    public native int initialize();

Also there is another exception i am facing ;

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetMethodID received NULL jclass in call to GetMethodID

My question is , first error of NoSuchMethodError was occured in MainActivity.java for initialise() method, where i am going wrong in declaration.

And second question is GetMethodID has occured in working code, how would i solve it ?

Sharing the code below,

**native-lib.cpp ( methods are properly declared in header file )**

```
#include "jni.h" 
#include "custom_main.h"
#include <android/log.h>

JavaVM *my_jvm;
jobject activity;

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_pkg_tpap_MainActivity_initialize(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

activity = env->NewGlobalRef(instance);
return my_initialize(my_jvm, activity);

}extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *aReserved) {

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "mylog", "OnLoad called");
my_jvm = vm;
return JNI_VERSION_1_6;

}extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "mylog", "OnUnload");
}
```

**MainActivity.java SNIPPET**

```
 static {

   System.loadLibrary("native-lib");

 }

 //this method is called on a button click to initialise the library
 public void initAppLib() {
    initialize();
 }

 //this method will give the data sent from the c++ lib
 public void getDataFromLib(String rawJson) {

    Log.e("responseData", rawJson);
 }

 //native method declared here
 public native int initialize();
```

**NativeProgram.cpp (the c++ source file in library from where i am trying to call java methods)**

```
void callJavaMethod(const std::string& stringToPrint) {

  JNIEnv* env;
  jint result1 = newVM->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

  if (result1 == JNI_EDETACHED) {
      result1 = newVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
  } 

  jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(activity);

  jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "getDataFromLib", "Ljava/lang/String");

   jstring data = env->NewStringUTF(stringToPrint.c_str());
   env->CallVoidMethod(activity, mid, data);

   env->DeleteLocalRef(clazz);

   if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
     env->ExceptionDescribe();
     env->ExceptionClear();
   }

   newVM->DetachCurrentThread();

}
```

Comment: Well, where is `getDataFromLib()`? And *please* put `extern "C" ...` on its own line every time, not like that.

Comment: @user207421 : question edited. please check. i have shared snippet only the entire code is written good. also written extern 'C' in original code whereever needed.

Comment: how do you declare the **native** method in Java?

Comment: @AlexCohn :  public native int initialize();
code also updated

Answer (score 1):

Use `"(Ljava/lang/String;)V"` for `GetMethodID()`. I think your function call syntax is incorrect.

I have done this previously, that I used a parameter syntax like this for my code and it worked. But I somehow cannot connect your exception to this error, so I'm not sure if this solves your problem. But I think that your function call parameters should be like this.

In addition, I personally use `RegisterNatives()` for registering my native methods in Java rather than simple naming convention method. I personally think it is more robust.